# C++ Tooltip function for checkbox

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

actually, my aim is to set a Tool tip for a **checkbox** function though, it doesn't seem to work. :/

the checkboxes are managed in a resource file using the format, BS_AUTOSTATE for every one of them. though I thought of initializing a tooltip for those checkboxes and a certain friend had suggested to use the following method,

```
text = dialog_message(IDC_FILE);
SetWindowText(GetDlgItem(m_hWnd, IDC_FILE), text));
```

and unfortunately, it didn't work. anyone has any other ideas for implementing tooltip without any other dependencies.

Comment: I'm not sure what that code you pasted is hoping to accomplish. To create a tooltip, you'll need to use a [tooltip control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb760246%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: I have never created a tooltip before, an example would be nice. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From @*andlab*'s link: How to Create a Tooltip for a Control or a rectangular area:
[Using Tooltip Controls](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb760252%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Tooltip requires common control version 4.70 or higher. Make sure project manifest is setup correctly.

You can use the `CreateToolTip` function below:

```
CreateToolTip(hWnd, hWndDialogItem, L"TESTING");
```

Example for a dialog box:

```
#include "windows.h"
#include "resource.h"
#include <commctrl.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "comctl32.lib")

void CreateToolTip(
    HWND hWndParent, /*HWND handle for the parent window, for example dialog box*/
    HWND hControlItem, /*HWND handle for the control item, for example checkbox*/
    PTSTR pszText /*text for the tool-tip*/)
{
    if (!hControlItem || !hWndParent || !pszText)
        return;

    // Create the tooltip. g_hInst is the global instance handle.
    HWND hwndTip = CreateWindowEx(NULL, TOOLTIPS_CLASS, NULL,
        WS_POPUP | TTS_ALWAYSTIP /* | TTS_BALLOON*/,
        CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT,
        hWndParent, NULL, GetModuleHandle(0), NULL);

    if (!hwndTip)
        return;

    // Associate the tooltip with the tool.
    TOOLINFO toolInfo = { 0 };
    toolInfo.cbSize = sizeof(toolInfo);
    toolInfo.hwnd = hWndParent;
    toolInfo.uFlags = TTF_IDISHWND | TTF_SUBCLASS;
    toolInfo.uId = (UINT_PTR)hControlItem;
    toolInfo.lpszText = pszText;
    if (!SendMessage(hwndTip, TTM_ADDTOOL, 0, (LPARAM)&toolInfo))
    {
        //OutputDebugString(L"TTM_ADDTOOL failed\nWrong project manifest!");
        MessageBox(0, TEXT("TTM_ADDTOOL failed\nWrong project manifest!"), 0, 0);
    }
}

BOOL CALLBACK DialogProc(HWND hDlg, UINT msg, WPARAM wp, LPARAM lp)
{
    switch (msg)
    {

    case WM_INITDIALOG:
    {
        HWND hDlgItem = GetDlgItem(hDlg, IDOK);
        if (hDlgItem)
        {
            CreateToolTip(hDlg, hDlgItem, L"TESTING");
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox(0, TEXT("Cannot find dialog item with IDOK identifier"), 0, 0);
        }
        break;
    }

    case WM_COMMAND:
        switch (wp)
        {
        case IDOK:
            EndDialog(hDlg, wp);
            break;
        case IDCANCEL:
            EndDialog(hDlg, wp);
            break;
        }
    }
    return FALSE;
}

int APIENTRY wWinMain(HINSTANCE hinst, HINSTANCE, LPTSTR, int nCmdShow)
{
    DialogBox(hinst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_DIALOG1), 0, DialogProc);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm new to coding so I'll appreciate a help on this,

Comment: ERROR: 'hDlg' was not declared on this scope.

Comment: I am not psychic, you have to explain what error you get. I updated the code, run it again and tell me if you get any error message. I replaced `OutputDebugString` with `MessageBox` incase you don't have a debugger.

Comment: I don't get any compilation errors, the Tooltip just doesn't show up. I  used, CreateToolTip(hDlg, IDC_EXECUTE, L"TESTING");

Comment: the IDC_EXECUTE handles a checkbox on the resource file.

Comment: Use the updated code which I put in the answer. It has message boxes which will show run time error. Just change `IDOK` to `IDC_EXECUTE` and then call `CreateToolTip(hDlg, hDlgItem, L"TESTING")` (the one I put in the answer). Are you using Visual Studio?

Comment: I get a different error now, :undefined reference to "WinMain@16"

Comment: I put `int APIENTRY wWinMain` for Unicode Window entry point, maybe *Code::Blocks* doesn't like that. Replace that line with the working code which you had earlier. If you don't have a big project I recommend *Visual Studio 2013*, it is free now. In *VS* you can create a new Window project automatically. Are you using Unicode or ANSI?

Comment: sorry for the trouble, I managed to get it to work. Thanks for your help !